# How do reduceLeft a List of Any type in scala

Tags: scala

I have a Map of

```
val m = Map(1 -> David, 2 -> Fred, 3 -> Bob, 4 -> Martin)
```

I want to get a value based on a key. I tried

```
p.map { case (k,v) => if (k == 1) v }
```

I get a List[Any]. But I want that value in a string. So I tried reduceLeft like this.

```
p.map { case (k,v) => if (k == 1) v }.toList.reduceLeft((a,b) => if (a.length > b.length) a else b )
```

Do I need to convert it to a list of String? Or how best can i get the value as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need `reduceLeft` here?

If you want to get a value from map based on the key use

```
m.getOrElse(key, default)
// where key is the numeric value in your case; Map[Int, String]
// and default will be the value returned if you don't find 
// any key
```

For example,

```
m.getOrElse(1, "David not found.")
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get a value based on a key.

You get a `List[Any]` because what happens if the key isn't equal to `1`? You don't have an `else` clause thus the compiler resolves the most general type it can, `Any`.

In general, that's not how you use a `Map`. A map contains key value pairs where the key is used for lookup of the value. The lookup is done via the `get` method which returns an `Option[T]`.

```
val one: Option[String] = map.get(1)
one.foreach(str => println(str))
```